# Insert node between chuck of xml based on xpath expression

Tags: xslt

variable xml_node contains 2 nodes.

```
<parameter name="FSC-A" type="30">
                                                        <is_log>false</is_log>
                                                        <is_quantitated>false</is_quantitated>
                                                        <min>0.0</min>
                                                        <max>262143.0</max>
                                                        <raw_index>1</raw_index>
                                                        <linear_index>1</linear_index>
                                                        <log_index>19</log_index>
                                                        <final_index>1</final_index>
                                                        <fl>FSC</fl>
                                                        <voltage>302</voltage>
                                                        <target>3</target>
                                                        <brightness>1.0</brightness>
                                                        <threshold>30000</threshold>
                                                        <trigger>true</trigger>
                                                        <labels_only>false</labels_only>
                                                        <biexp_scale>-1</biexp_scale>
                                                        <comp_biexp_scale>-1</comp_biexp_scale>
                                                        <manual_biexp_scale>0</manual_biexp_scale>
                                                        <can_be_compensated>false</can_be_compensated>
                                            </parameter>
                                            <parameter name="SSC-A" type="30">
                                                        <is_log>false</is_log>
                                                        <is_quantitated>false</is_quantitated>
                                                        <min>0.0</min>
                                                        <max>262143.0</max>
                                                        <raw_index>2</raw_index>
                                                        <linear_index>2</linear_index>
                                                        <log_index>20</log_index>
                                                        <final_index>2</final_index>
                                                        <fl>SSC</fl>
                                                        <voltage>307</voltage>
                                                        <target>3</target>
                                                        <brightness>1.0</brightness>
                                                        <threshold>5000</threshold>
                                                        <trigger>false</trigger>
                                                        <labels_only>false</labels_only>
                                                        <biexp_scale>-1</biexp_scale>
                                                        <comp_biexp_scale>-1</comp_biexp_scale>
                                                        <manual_biexp_scale>0</manual_biexp_scale>
                                                        <can_be_compensated>false</can_be_compensated>
                                            </parameter>
```

my xpath is //parameter[@name = 'FSC-A']

I like to insert $extra_node after this xpath

variable extra_node contain this node.

```
<parameter name="SSC-H" type="30">
                                                        <is_log>false</is_log>
                                                        <is_quantitated>false</is_quantitated>
                                                        <min>0.0</min>
                                                        <max>262143.0</max>
                                                        <raw_index>2</raw_index>
                                                        <linear_index>2</linear_index>
                                                        <log_index>20</log_index>
                                                        <final_index>2</final_index>
                                                        <fl>SSC</fl>
                                                        <voltage>307</voltage>
                                                        <target>3</target>
                                                        <brightness>1.0</brightness>
                                                        <threshold>5000</threshold>
                                                        <trigger>false</trigger>
                                                        <labels_only>false</labels_only>
                                                        <biexp_scale>-1</biexp_scale>
                                                        <comp_biexp_scale>-1</comp_biexp_scale>
                                                        <manual_biexp_scale>0</manual_biexp_scale>
                                                        <can_be_compensated>false</can_be_compensated>
                                            </parameter>
```

So the final would look like

```
<parameter name="FSC-A" type="30">
                                                        <is_log>false</is_log>
                                                        <is_quantitated>false</is_quantitated>
                                                        <min>0.0</min>
                                                        <max>262143.0</max>
                                                        <raw_index>1</raw_index>
                                                        <linear_index>1</linear_index>
                                                        <log_index>19</log_index>
                                                        <final_index>1</final_index>
                                                        <fl>FSC</fl>
                                                        <voltage>302</voltage>
                                                        <target>3</target>
                                                        <brightness>1.0</brightness>
                                                        <threshold>30000</threshold>
                                                        <trigger>true</trigger>
                                                        <labels_only>false</labels_only>
                                                        <biexp_scale>-1</biexp_scale>
                                                        <comp_biexp_scale>-1</comp_biexp_scale>
                                                        <manual_biexp_scale>0</manual_biexp_scale>
                                                        <can_be_compensated>false</can_be_compensated>
                                            </parameter>
                                            <parameter name="SSC-H" type="30">
                                                        <is_log>false</is_log>
                                                        <is_quantitated>false</is_quantitated>
                                                        <min>0.0</min>
                                                        <max>262143.0</max>
                                                        <raw_index>2</raw_index>
                                                        <linear_index>2</linear_index>
                                                        <log_index>20</log_index>
                                                        <final_index>2</final_index>
                                                        <fl>SSC</fl>
                                                        <voltage>307</voltage>
                                                        <target>3</target>
                                                        <brightness>1.0</brightness>
                                                        <threshold>5000</threshold>
                                                        <trigger>false</trigger>
                                                        <labels_only>false</labels_only>
                                                        <biexp_scale>-1</biexp_scale>
                                                        <comp_biexp_scale>-1</comp_biexp_scale>
                                                        <manual_biexp_scale>0</manual_biexp_scale>
                                                        <can_be_compensated>false</can_be_compensated>
                                            </parameter>
                                            <parameter name="SSC-A" type="30">
                                                        <is_log>false</is_log>
                                                        <is_quantitated>false</is_quantitated>
                                                        <min>0.0</min>
                                                        <max>262143.0</max>
                                                        <raw_index>2</raw_index>
                                                        <linear_index>2</linear_index>
                                                        <log_index>20</log_index>
                                                        <final_index>2</final_index>
                                                        <fl>SSC</fl>
                                                        <voltage>307</voltage>
                                                        <target>3</target>
                                                        <brightness>1.0</brightness>
                                                        <threshold>5000</threshold>
                                                        <trigger>false</trigger>
                                                        <labels_only>false</labels_only>
                                                        <biexp_scale>-1</biexp_scale>
                                                        <comp_biexp_scale>-1</comp_biexp_scale>
                                                        <manual_biexp_scale>0</manual_biexp_scale>
                                                        <can_be_compensated>false</can_be_compensated>
                                            </parameter>
```

I tried this, nut it doesn't work, because I don't know what I am doing.  Can someone please help?

```
    <xsl:variable name="xpath" select="//root/parameter[@name = 'FSC-A']"/>
                                            <xsl:copy-of select="custom:insertAfter($xml_node,$xpath,saxon:parse($extra_node))"/>
                                            <!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ insertAfter Function~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
<xsl:function name="custom:insertAfter">
        <xsl:param name="doc" as="node()"/>
        <!--ONE NODE: root node of xml chunk where insert should be done -->
        <xsl:param name="xpath" as="xs:string"/>
        <!--STRING: xpath of node after which new node will be placed -->
        <xsl:param name="insert_nodes" as="node()*"/>
        <!--ONE OR MORE NODES: node(s) that will be inserted after specified node -->
        <xsl:variable name="insert_after_nodes" select="custom:evaluateXPath($xpath,$doc)" as="node()*"/>
        <xsl:variable name="result" as="node()*">
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="insert_node" select="$doc">
                <xsl:with-param name="insert_after_nodes" select="$insert_after_nodes" tunnel="yes"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="insert_nodes" select="$insert_nodes" tunnel="yes"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:copy-of select="ext:node-set($result)"/>
    </xsl:function>
    <xsl:function name="custom:evaluateXPath">
        <xsl:param name="path" as="xs:string"/>
        <xsl:param name="context"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="$context">
            <!-- Change context document -->
            <xsl:sequence select="saxon:evaluate($path)"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:function>
```

Comment: You don't need a custom function to insert a node in XSLT. Where is this code from? Did you write it?

Comment: No I didn't write it.  What else do you suggest?  Do you have an easier solution?

Comment: **First off**: *Never* use code that you did not write (or do not fully understand). **Second**: If you did not write the code you show in a StackOverflow question, say so and say where you got it from. **Third** Show more of your XSLT. Make a syntactically valid file (compiles and runs) that does not quite do what you want and include it in your question.

Comment: Ok, first of all- what XSL processor are you using, and does it support XSLT2? Secondly, can you elaborate on 'it doesn't work'? Is there an error, or are you not getting the output you expect?

Comment: This project is rather complex and it a large xslt.  I am using altova supports zxlt version 2.0 with saxon processor.  How can I attach my input and xslt file here?

Comment: Please visit these links.  You will find my input and stylesheet.  Thank you

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1SyR8KN4yirum2WdcmjiIVnEO6BU2FUoA9gWMu09fBsE/edit
 https://docs.google.com/document/d/1j0Lpcpgb3mQDqyldtS4eKaShmWx6J_VS893q2OFI9UE/edit?usp=sharing